# Minting 3D files onto opensea

Tags: remix, nft, mining, opensea, alchemy

I am new and I am building an NFT collection on Open Sea for my personal project.  I have watched a couple of videos from Alchemy, the ERC721 smart contract video outlined how to upload and host files on filebase and use the CID to mint NFT's onto open sea. However, when you upload 3D .glb files onto filebase or any supported file format, and clicking on the CID it downloads the file onto your device instead of opening it on a browser like a .png or .gif. I dont want it to download but instead have it show on opensea like the rest of my NFT's. I am aware browsers can't render 3d image files. I am trying to explore other ways but havet found anything yet. Is there anyone who could help resolve this?

Comment: Have you considered creating "copies" of the 3D .glb files, but converted into .png or .gif formats? That way, you can just load the .png or .gif for the NFT representation. Is it required for you to attcah .glb files to the NFT metadata?

Comment: Well if I convert them to png or gif files it takes away from the interactive 360 functionality of the file and users can no longer interact and view their NFT in 360 view. Thats why I moved towards supported 3D file formats.

Comment: yeah makes sense -- maybe you can try a browser extension like this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbx-gltf-glb-3d-viewer/ddmladejiediokofnpdflciecailajkp

Comment: Even if I do add a browser extension. It will show in 3d on my browser. How will it be 3D on opensea when i mint the nft.

Comment: Did some searching and found this example on OpenSea: https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e/74897159549861964643456459151095158543386453038678965139265938706342877331956

Comment: That led me to google some docs around supported 3D file formats, and it turns out you should be able to upload your GLB files directly to OpenSea! If you want to create your own contract you should be able to do so as well, that would just require some more configuration to make sure you're meeting the OpenSea metadata standards.

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenSea metadata documentation, we can see that GLB and GLTF files are supported, which may help you out here: https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards

I found this great walkthrough of how to upload 3D files onto OpenSea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Luep5gAs1LM

If you are able to create a GLB or GLTF file, you can upload that 3D model to create a 3D interactive experience when shoppers are browsing your asset listing.

1. Make a model in blender
2. Export as GLB or GLTF file
3. Suggested specs: Single model, no more than 5000 tris, texture format jpg or png, texture size no more than 1024x1024, PBR materials, size no more than 20MB
4. Go to opensea.io and create a new item
5. Upload your GLB (or GLTF) file, upload a preview image
6. Now you're done!

Here's another question that could help with troubleshooting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124838/opensea-not-generating-preview-for-3d-model-glb